# xcode11 seguing from A view to B on iPad, the B view does not fill screen

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, xcode11

I have two view controllers, A and B, each under its view controller scene.
When I run the app on an iPhone the segue from A to B goes from full screen to full screen as expected.
When I run the app on an iPad the opening view, A, fills the entire screen but the second view, B, is presented in a square box quite smaller than the full screen size.

Use Full Screen (deprecated) is checked.

Here are the view and segue definitions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that whereas on an iPhone a segue from VC **A** to VC **B** presented a VC which was full screen, on the iPad the VC was presented as a square that did not fill the screen.

Solution:
Clicking on the segue between A and B brings up **storyboard segue** in the left column. On the Kind DM select **modally**. This brings up a new menu. In the **kind** DM select **Full Screen**.